# how to list _ALL_ rules allowing reply to incoming ICMP echo packet

Tags: windows, firewall, netsh

Trying to list all %subj% rules. Problem is that `netsh` have parameter `protocol` on rule deletion `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=all protocol=icmpv4` but it HAVE NOT such parameter on rule display `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule protocol=icmpv4` it print `'protocol' is not a valid argument for this command.`. Anyone hoave idea how to list such rules?